# Script Generalisation

Tags: javascript

My script:

```js
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
function myFunction0() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup0");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
function myFunction1() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup1");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
function myFunction2() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup2");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
function myFunction3() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup3");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
</div>
```

I want to generalize the script for multiple popups placed in different places.  Actually I have only distinguish href tags (instead div i using a in my site).
Anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```js
for (let popup of document.querySelectorAll('.popup')) {
    popup.onclick = function () {
        this.querySelector('.popuptext').classList.toggle('show');
    };
}
```

```css
.popuptext { display: none }

.popuptext.show { display: inline; }
```

```html
<div class="popup">Click me 1!
  <span class="popuptext">Popup text 1...</span>
</div>

<div class="popup">Click me 2!
  <span class="popuptext">Popup text 2...</span>
</div>

<div class="popup">Click me 3!
  <span class="popuptext">Popup text 3...</span>
</div>

<div class="popup">Click me 4!
  <span class="popuptext">Popup text 4...</span>
</div>
```

You don't need separate IDs on your elements. The `onclick` handler can simply use `this` to get the clicked element.

Comment: Your code is very simple.  AND that is what i want which is very superb.  Thankyou!!!!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using JavaScript at all in this instance, when the browser does this for you?

```html
<p>Example from <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary">MDN</a></p>
<details>
    <summary>I have keys but no locks. I have space but no room. You can enter but can't leave. What am I?</summary>
    A keyboard.
</details>
```

---

To answer the actual question, just pass in the target element (in this case, its ID) as an argument to the function.

```
function toggle(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}
```

You can of course generalise this further by passing the name of the class to toggle, but that's up to you.